# Convert json file to dataframe using RJSONIO package R

Tags: r, dataframe, rjsonio

I am new to R facing issue in converting json file to dataframe. I have the json file which looks like below:

```
json_file = '[{"id": "abc", "model": "honda", "date": "20190604", "cols": {"action": 15, "values": 18, "not": 29}},
  {"id": "abc", "model": "honda", "date": "20190604", "cols": {"hello": 14, "hi": 85, "wow": 14}},
  {"id": "mno", "model": "ford", "date": "20190604", "cols": {"yesterday": 21, "today": 21, "tomorrow": 29}},
  {"id": "mno", "model": "ford", "date": "20190604", "cols": {"docs": 25, "ok": 87, "none": 42}}]'
```

I want to convert the above json file to dataframe in below format:

**Expected Result**

```
df = 
id  model      date  cols  values_cols
abc honda  20190604 action   15   
abc honda  20190604 values   18 
abc honda  20190604 not      29 
abc honda  20190604 hello    14 
abc honda  20190604 hi       85 
abc honda  20190604 wow      14 
mno ford  20190604 yesterday 21   
mno ford  20190604 today     21 
mno ford  20190604 tomorrow  29 
mno ford  20190604 docs      25 
mno ford  20190604 ok        87
```

**My Solution**

```
require(RJSONIO)
df = fromJSON(json_file)
```

**My result**

```
  id model     date cols id.1 model.1   date.1 cols.1 id.2 model.2   date.2 cols.2 id.3 model.3   date.3 cols.3
action abc honda 20190604   15  abc   honda 20190604     14  mno    ford 20190604     21  mno    ford 20190604     25
values abc honda 20190604   18  abc   honda 20190604     85  mno    ford 20190604     21  mno    ford 20190604     87
not    abc honda 20190604   29  abc   honda 20190604     14  mno    ford 20190604     29  mno    ford 20190604     42
```

It is incorrect because it is taking index which should come as column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
> library(jsonlite)
> library(tidyverse)
> 
> json_file = '[
+   {"id": "abc", 
+     "model": "honda", 
+     "date": "20190604", 
+     "cols": {"action": 15, "values": 18, "not": 29}},
+   {"id": "abc", 
+     "model": "honda", 
+     "date": "20190604", 
+     "cols": {"hello": 14, "hi": 85, "wow": 14}},
+   {"id": "mno", 
+     "model": "ford", 
+     "date": "20190604", 
+     "cols": {"yesterday": 21, "today": 21, "tomorrow": 29}},
+   {"id": "mno", 
+     "model": "ford", 
+     "date": "20190604", 
+     "cols": {"docs": 25, "ok": 87, "none": 42}}]'
> 
> df <- fromJSON(json_file)
> 
> # need to convert the internal dataframes in 'cols' to vectors
> x <- map_df(seq_along(df),
+          ~tibble(id = df$id[.x],
+                  model = df$model[.x],
+                  date = df$date[.x],
+                  cols = names(df$cols),
+                  values = sapply(df$cols, '[', .x)
+          )
+ )
> 
> ## remove NAs
> x[complete.cases(x), ]
# A tibble: 12 x 5
   id    model date     cols      values
   <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>      <int>
 1 abc   honda 20190604 action        15
 2 abc   honda 20190604 values        18
 3 abc   honda 20190604 not           29
 4 abc   honda 20190604 hello         14
 5 abc   honda 20190604 hi            85
 6 abc   honda 20190604 wow           14
 7 mno   ford  20190604 yesterday     21
 8 mno   ford  20190604 today         21
 9 mno   ford  20190604 tomorrow      29
10 mno   ford  20190604 docs          25
11 mno   ford  20190604 ok            87
12 mno   ford  20190604 none          42
>
```